# ng-repeat animation on delete from filtered list

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list that shows 2 different portions of the same array by using a filter on the `ng-repeat`: deleted and non-deleted items. I didn't want to have 2 different lists therefore I'm filtering the array from within the `ng-repeat` declaration.

When removing items from the viewed list, I want them to animate using fade-out animation, and it works just fine. However, when switching between the 2 views (changing the list's filter) I don't want that animation but the `ng-leave` animation is triggered anyhow.

**Q:**  how can I keep the animation when clicking the "delete" button but skip the animation when switching between "visible" and "deleted" filters?

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-init="myFilter='visible'">Filter:
  <button ng-class="{'active':myFilter==='visible'}" ng-click="myFilter='visible'">Visible</button>
  <button ng-class="{'active':myFilter==='deleted'}" ng-click="myFilter='deleted'">Deleted</button>
</div>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl" >

  <div ng-repeat="item in (items | filter:{deleted: (myFilter==='deleted'?true:false) } )" class="repeat-item">
    {{item}} <div class="delete" ng-show="myFilter==='visible'" ng-click="remove($index)">delete</div> 
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.repeat-item.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
}

.repeat-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
}

.repeat-item.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 30px;
}
```

**Working plunkr:** 
http://plnkr.co/edit/aeYCIu?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

hi i had posted plunker check.

add just

```
class="default-style" ng-class="{'repeat-item': myFilter === 'visible'}">
```

and add css class

```
.default-style{
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

and everything working

http://plnkr.co/edit/WgRYTjVLBNaxXNeXX5wG?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve it: when switching from "deleted" to "visible" the list items are still animated.

Comment: i had checked when you click deleted animation happened ( visible to deleted ) , but if you click visible no animation happened ( deleted to visible ).